trying to connect inskam camera to my flutter application
am trying to connect an Inskam camera to my Flutter application and display its video feed. I've been using the wifi_iot package for Wi-Fi connectivity and the video_player package to display the video. Despite my efforts, the app fails to connect to the camera's Wi-Fi or display the video feed correctly.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:wifi_iot/wifi_iot.dart';
import 'camera_service.dart'; // Assuming this is a custom service you've created
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class CameraExample2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraExample2State createState() => _CameraExample2State();
}

class _CameraExample2State extends State<CameraExample2> {
  VideoPlayerController? _controller;
  Future<void>? _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  final CameraService _cameraService = CameraService('192.168.100.41'); // Replace with your camera's IP address
  bool _isConnected = false;
  String _statusMessage = 'Connecting to Wi-Fi...';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _connectToWifi();
  }

  Future<void> _connectToWifi() async {
    try {
      // Request location permission
      if (await Permission.location.request().isGranted) {
        // Replace with your camera's Wi-Fi SSID and password
        const ssid = 'inskam-FC10E16';
        const password = '12345678';

        // Enable Wi-Fi if it's not enabled
        bool wifiEnabled = await WiFiForIoTPlugin.isEnabled();
        print('Wi-Fi enabled: $wifiEnabled');
        if (!wifiEnabled) {
          await WiFiForIoTPlugin.setEnabled(true);
          print('Wi-Fi has been enabled');
        }

        // Check available Wi-Fi networks (for debugging purposes)
        var wifiNetworks = await WiFiForI

i tried using the wifi manager but there are no results
